# Ubuntu-MATE 21.04 Installer Freezes on PC Install (not a VM)

Tags: boot, system-installation, mate, 21.04

The Ubuntu MATE 21.04 fails to "launch" when trying to do a clean install on my PC. The installer starts up and shows the green Ubuntu logo and the small circles cycle through for about 30 seconds and then the system hangs. I have tried this multiple times, on two different USB drives, and verified the checksums. I also wiped the drive clean once and downloaded the Ubuntu 21.04 (non-mate), but it on the same USB drive, and it boots up just fine.

My computer has been running Ubuntu MATE 20.10 without issues, and before that 20.04, 19.10, etc back to 18.04. No new hardware has been added to my computer.

My hardware specs are:

- AMD Ryzen 7 2700X Eight-Core Processor
- 32 GB RAM
- ASUS ROG STRIX B450-F GAMING Motherboard
- NVidia GeForce RTX 2070 GPU
- Sabrent 1TB NVMe M.2 Boot drive
- 1GB Ethernet port on the Motherboard

I also have a couple USB devices plugged in:

- USB 3 Thumb Drive with Ubuntu-MATE 21.04 installer image (via BalenaEtcher)
- USB KVM Switch (only used for keyboard and mouse; video directly plugged to monitor)
- Logitech HD Pro Webcam C920
- USB Microphone - BCMaster
- Multi-card reader with NO external cards (CF, SD, etc...) plugged in
- External LG USB Bluray/DVD/CD drive that is currently powered down for the install

I took a look at the installer logs written to the USB drive, and in the auth.log file it starts like this:

```
Apr 25 10:35:28 ubuntu-mate systemd-logind[2294]: New seat seat0.
Apr 25 10:35:28 ubuntu-mate systemd-logind[2294]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event1 (Power Button)
Apr 25 10:35:28 ubuntu-mate systemd-logind[2294]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event0 (Power Button)
Apr 25 10:35:28 ubuntu-mate systemd-logind[2294]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event5 (Logitech K800)
Apr 25 10:35:46 ubuntu-mate python3: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user ubuntu-mate by (uid=0)
Apr 25 10:35:46 ubuntu-mate systemd-logind[2294]: New session c1 of user ubuntu-mate.
Apr 25 10:35:46 ubuntu-mate systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user ubuntu-mate by (uid=0)
Apr 25 10:36:11 ubuntu-mate dbus-daemon[2273]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.RealtimeKit1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
Apr 25 10:36:36 ubuntu-mate dbus-daemon[2273]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.RealtimeKit1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
Apr 25 10:37:01 ubuntu-mate dbus-daemon[2273]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.RealtimeKit1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
Apr 25 10:37:26 ubuntu-mate dbus-daemon[2273]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.RealtimeKit1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
Apr 25 10:37:51 ubuntu-mate dbus-daemon[2273]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.RealtimeKit1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
Apr 25 10:38:16 ubuntu-mate dbus-daemon[2273]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.RealtimeKit1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
```

The last message repeats for eternity every 30 seconds until I hard shutdown the PC.

To repeat, I am currently running Ubuntu Mate 20.10 on this hardware and it has been running Ubuntu Mate for a couple of years without issue. I have tried the installer on two different USB drives (16Gb) and end up with the same auth.log messages.

I have tried searching for a similar issue, but all I find about that issue are some references to a RHEL install.

All suggestions appreciated. I can look for items in other logs, but not sure what would be useful to post. Thanks a bunch in advance. I really want to perform a clean install of Ubuntu Mate 21.04 on my PC.

Comment: Maybe report as a bug. https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/report-ubuntu-bug.html.en

Comment: Please also report to http://ubuntu-mate.community/ . Simplest way to get 21.04 would be `update-manager -cd` on installed 20.10.

Comment: @N0rbert - I usually do a clean install when going from one release to ensure I start with a fresh clean drive. Since the installer is failing to fully launch, I am a little worried that it may not boot after the upgrade to 21.04 from 20.10. I keep my system up to date most of the time; rarely am I more than 5 days out from available patches. Thanks for the suggestion for ubuntu-mate.community.  Will post there as well.